# LARAVEL Eloquent query multiple schema

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Do i need to create multiple connection to access different database/schema.  Cant I use with one dbconnection.  Is there a way to pass the database name  in the laravel eloquent or db builder? Currently in raw php i use one connection to query the different schema.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create different connections to your database.php file and then pass them to your eloquent models.

```
'mysql1' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => 'db1',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],

// connection 2
'mysql2' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => 'db2',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Suppose i have model User.php uses mysql connection named mysql1

inside my model i will add :

```
protected $connection = 'mysql1';
```

if i want to use mysql connection named mysql2
then i will use

```
protected $connection = 'mysql2';
```

Here i am setting connections statically in to models.

Answer (score 5):

In Eloquent, I use DB:connection() to set my named connection, like so:

```
        $query = DB::connection('db_connection_name')->table($this->table)
```

If you weren't aware, the database connections are named in the config app/config/database.php

Comment: Just to clarifyI: Paul Herome Bordallo, DB isn't Eloquent.  DB is its own class outside of the Eloquent system in Laravel.  Eloquent is based on the Model class, DB is its own class.

"All Eloquent models extend Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model class." - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Comment: Yes. I said in Eloquent as in inside an Eloquent class method, I found that it worked. It’s not documented so it may change. But it does set the db connection in a way unavailable to Eloquent and Eloquent’s own methods aren’t directly involved in that.